# Django template: Can't pass an int and a string from path to view

Tags: python, django

Having issues passing values from template to view, the int value is fine but the 2 string values are not.

The string values i.3 and i.4 print fine in template, but when passed as url parameters the full url cannot be found.

```
Reverse for 'world' with keyword arguments '{'some_id': 0, 'some_val': '', 'some_val_2': ''}' not found.
```

template:

```
{% for item in my_config %}
<tr>
  {% for i in item %}
    {{ i.3 }}
    {{ i.4 }}
    {{some_id}}
            <a href="{% url 'hello:world' some_id=some_id some_val=i.3 some_val_2=i.4 %}">hello</a>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>{% endfor %}
```

Getting NoReverseMatch error.

Rest of my code:

urls.py

```
path(r'^world/<int:some_id>/<some_val>/<some_val_2>/', views.world, name='world'),
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

It works with only the int parameter.

```
<a href="{% url 'hello:world' some_id=some_id %}">hello</a>

path(r'^world/<int:some_id>/', views.world, name='world'),
```

But when adding the i.3 and i.4 strings it does not. I have tried hard coding strings and that does seem to work. It's like the i.3 and i.4 are not resolving inside the {% %}

Comment: What are `i.3` and `i.4`? or how is `item` defined?

Comment: You are mixing `re_path` with path: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path. Use `path('world/<int:some_id>/<some_val>/<some_val_2>/'`

Comment: i.3 and i.4 are strings.

Comment: Can you check that every iteration of i.3 and i.4 have values? If just one doesn't, the error will show.